# How to keep kajal stay in place?

Tags: comfort

I have bulging eyes so whenever I put kajal in my eyes it spread around my eyes and it looks bad.How can I keep kajal stay in eyes and do not spread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very light film of oil or wax (softened, if needed, by heating and mixing in a small amount of vegetable oil or animal fat), defining the area where the kajal (kohl) is intended to go, will help it stay where it's put and still allow easy removal when it's time for that.  You can apply the oil with an eye liner brush or similar very fine brush (a small artist's "filbert" brush will even work with wax).

Answer (score -1):

Follow are 6 simple tips and stop eyeliner smudging under eyes.
Use Good Eyeliner Formula. A good eyeliner formula itself will never budge or smear off your eyes.

1.Apply Concealer In The Under Eye Area.

2.Try The Layering Technique.

3.Apply Face Powder.

4.Use Oil Absorbent Sheets.

5.Use Primer.

6.Seal It Up.

Comment: Its look like Copy paste. If you have any link then kindly share the link of website

Comment: No, im facing this problem, that's why I m asking here